# Web service not accessible after changing application name in Grails

Tags: web-services, grails, grails-services

I have a SOUP web service in my Grails application. It was accessible before changing application name in `application.properties` from `localhost:8080/appName/Services/` but now this gives `page not found` error after changing the appName. I don't know why this is happening.

Comment: Try a `grails clean` and start app again. Also include your new `application.properties` in the question.

Comment: Are you trying to run from IDE or try it on web-container?

Comment: I tried both from IDE and web-container.

Comment: Why I've asked. Once I have such problem on remote server. I renamed app and forget to change .war name in deploy script, so deployed old war (=

Answer (score 0):

Are you providing the same appName in the url as in application.properties ?

Comment: if you are providing so, then you need to restart your application also, for the changes to take effect.